# Proper stsadm commands to update SharePoint Solution/Feature

Tags: sharepoint, solution, stsadm, feature-upgrade

What are the proper stsadm commands in sequence to force an upgrade to a SharePoint solution. I have tried

> C:>"C:\Program Files\Common
>   Files\Microsoft Shared\web server
>   extensions\12\BIN\stsadm.exe" -o
>   deploysolution -name "MySolution.wsp"
>   -immediate -allcontenturls -allowGacDeployment -allowCasPolicies -force

followed by

> C:>"C:\Program Files\Common
>   Files\Microsoft Shared\web server
>   extensions\12\BIN\stsadm.exe" -o
>   execadmsvcjobs

It seems to deploy and shows the solution as having a deployment time of when I push these commands but my files don't appear to get updated and new files don't appear.

Am I missing something? Do I need to do an **IISReset /noforce** after processing these commands.

Thanks,
Josh Lewis

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The proper way is to use the -o upgradesolution command.  In most cases there is no need to retract and delete the solution and reinstall it.  Be sure and follow it up with an -o execadmsvcjobs as usual.

Answer (score 3):

```
stsadm -o retractsolution -name ... -immediate -allcontenturls
stsadm -o execadmsvcjobs
stsadm -o deletesolution -name ...
stsadm -o addsolution -filename ... 
stsadm -o deploysolution -name ... -immediate -allcontenturls -allowgacdeployment -allowcaspolicies
stsadm -o execadmsvcjobs
```

A few warnings:

Sometimes you have to start with deactivating the feature first (stsadm -o deactivatefeature). When I changed a Site feature containing a list template to a Web feature I ended up with double links on the create page. So i had to install the old feature again, deactivate it and then reinstall the new feature.

Do NOT use -force if you're not sure what you are doing. If you use it with the -o deletesolution command you may end up with old versions of files on some or all of your servers. Such problems can be hard to track down and it gives you a lot of extra work, especially if you have multiple front end servers.

Answer (score 1):

1. Ghosted files don't get updated.
2. stsadm -o execadmsvcjobs will proces any job, that is late on processing
3. reactivate features, Those that contain content (next time; use feature stapling!)
4. upgrading solutions will not always automatically install new features (yes, install, not activate). Check this.

Answer (score 0):

An IISRESET might also be worthwhile but you could try to run the "SharePoint Products and Technologies Configuration Wizard", AKA PSCONFIG.EXE

Located at
C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\12\BIN

It'll syncronize the informations that are on the Database, the IIS and the Binaries. It's necessary to run it when you apply a Service Pack.

Also make sure that all servers on your farm has access to the Central Administration and that you ran the PSCONFIG on all of them.

Answer (score 0):

I think because you are supplying the -force parameter in the deploysolution command you are actually suppressing the error message that would probably be displayed - along the lines of Solution already exists. As stated previously either do retract->deploy or upgrade (depending on your scenario).