# SharePoint Deploy WSP to another server

Tags: sharepoint-2007

I made my first WSP with VS2008, and used WSP Builder to build and deploy to my local install (SharePoint and VS2008 on same dev box).
Now I want to get the WSP onto a staging server, in general, how is this done, copying the WSP to the remote server's file system then using STSADM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. For more information, see the following related questions:

- [Deploying SharePoint Solution using VSeWSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1326814/deploying-sharepoint-solution-using-vsewss)
- [Building a WSP File on the Build Machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274962/building-a-wsp-file-on-the-build-machine)
- [SharePoint wsp solution: How to Deploy Globally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1276584/sharepoint-wsp-solution-how-to-deploy-globally)
- [SharePoint: Will deploying a WSP install DLL’s in Gac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1339188/sharepoint-will-deploying-a-wsp-install-dlls-in-gac)
- [Proper stsadm commands to update SharePoint Solution/Feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/748261/proper-stsadm-commands-to-update-sharepoint-solution-feature)